# In Java, I am trying for find a prime number between the range form 10 to 99, but I received that all the numbers in the range are not prime number

Tags: java

I have tried the program and I got wrong output  kindly help me to solve the problem that I have

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the Starting Number : ");
        int snum=obj.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the Ending Number : ");
        int endnum=obj.nextInt();

        Boolean isprime=true;

        for(int i=snum;i<endnum;i++)
        {
            for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
            {
                if(i%j==0)
                {
                    isprime=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(isprime)
            {
                System.out.println(i+" is PRIME NUMBER");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(i+" is NOT PRIME NUMBER");
            }           
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Move `Boolean isprime=true;` to the next line of the first `for` statement.

Comment: Btw I would use `boolean` instead of `Boolean` here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-initialize isprime each time in loop:

```
for(int i=snum;i<endnum;i++)
{
isprime = true;
    for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
    {
        if(i%j==0)
        {
            isprime=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isprime)
    {
        System.out.println(i+" is PRIME NUMBER");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(i+" is NOT PRIME NUMBER");
    }           
}
```